# Why is mind/body duality so widely accepted?

Tags: epistemology, descartes, dualism

It seems strange that Cartesian mind/body duality is so widely accepted, given that it leads to scepticism around the possibility of human knowledge.

Why is it so widely accepted, and how do its adherents escape its seemingly inevitable scepticism (or come to terms with it)?

Please support any answer with cited references to reputable sources.

Comment: This link on Spinoza's epistemology might be useful to others: https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/14957/7/07_chapter%202.pdf

Comment: As for being active on SEP and having doubts about my propositions, I cite the following list that interferes with ascertainment of certainty: illusion, hallucination, memory, fallacy, bias, and deception, including self-deception. I have erred, I do err, and I will continue to err. Therefore, statements of fact are open to debate and certainty. I once believed in the Luther's god, and now I see 'god' is a linguistic device that doesn't represent some sort of omnipotent being is a psychological construct with an emotional purpose...

Comment: Hence according to my experience and understanding, ['true believers'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_True_Believer) are a manifestation of a psychological phenomenon where adequate doubt to build an empirically valid representation is deficient. Some psychologists go so far to consider a certainty of knowledge a [psychological syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-believer_syndrome), though in the spirit of R. D. Laing, I am skeptical of such normative 'diagnoses'.

Comment: How can I be a member of SEP and doubt the veracity of my claims? Because I am no ['true Scotsman'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Scotsman) nor am I bound to believe they exist outside of human construction.

Comment: Hi Charles, I edited because I felt the substance of your question was being lost in the rhetoric surrounding it. Also, not everyone does accept dualism so "universal" was not appropriate. Finally, do you want to add some support for your assumption that Cartesian dualism must inevitably lead to skepticism? I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying you'll get better answers if you detail where you see the connection.

Comment: Widely accepted by whom? Analytic philosophers prefer physicalism and theists deny that it leads to skepticism. If you mean "the folk" they "accept" it mostly as a good enough stub for everyday transactions and skepticism is dismissed out of hand in that context.

Comment: It seems to me you confuse the epistemological position of external realism with the metaphysical position of dualism. For some 50 years now, the former is prevalent while the latter is rarely held. Metaphysical positions in general are mostly a derivative of what really is an epistemological position these days IMHO. Many philosophers refuse metaphysics as such as being nonsensical. Btw both internal and external realism are inconsistent.

Comment: @J D- I wish you had entered your comment as an Answer. I think there is some substance to what you are saying.

Comment: @J D- As to your last comment, my question is, in your terms, why do you believe that your beliefs, 'do not exist outside of human construction'. In other words, who taught you that? Or, what established philosopher would you site in support of such a belief?

Comment: @Philip Hocking- 'Many philosophers refuse metaphysics as such as nonsensical. BTW both internal and external realism are inconsistent.'  Plus, 'over 50 years'..., well over 2,000years of metaphysics beginning with Aristotle, refute any currently held misconceptions like materialism. And, realism is inconsistent with what? And, which philosophers 'refuse metaphysics' and what weight do their assertions carry?

Comment: Internal  and external realism are internally inconsistent, see *The Limits of Realism* by Tim Button. Ever heard of minor authors like Putnam (the late, there are at least three 'Putnams' in his opus) and Rorty? Button bases most of his arguments on the former. Basically all pragmatists are standing in some way or the other in a Hegelian tradition and reject dualism. Also, you have been asked to substantiate your own claims, how about doing that first? Why is materialism a 'misconception' and in which ways? If you are an internal realist, what do you base this on?

Comment: @ Chris Sunami- My usage of 'universally', 'materialism', 'scepticism', are meant to refer to the broad category of defining the mind and body as two differentiated entities. Materialism, in like manner indicates those who posit the realm of sensible objects as containing the only possible source of knowledge. And scepticism  indicates any contention that human perception is flawed and requires some 'objective' support, demonstration or proof.  The analytic and phenomenological systems tend to act as if all other forms of philosophy have been dismissed as irrelevant. Many of us beg to differ.

Comment: @J D Thanks for that link to the paper. After reviewing it, it serves the purpose of laying out Spinoza's epistemology well enough. Thanks J D

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking- Thanks for your comments. Give me a little time to work on that 'materialism' point. Regards, CMS

Comment: What @PhilipKlöcking is pointing out is that it is possible to be a materialist and reject dualism as in Gilbert Ryle or Daniel Dennett's [eliminative materialism (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/materialism-eliminative/) which is a monism. George Lakoff in _Philosophy in the Flesh_ rejects dualism and settles for three primary ontologies (the neural being the third). The mind-body duality is an ontological position that squares with the very intuitive [naive realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism)...

Comment: and if I'm not mistaken Berkeley takes the opposite tack and has a monism where thought is the primary 'stuff' rather than material. As for construction, all thought is a byproduct of material if one even tentatively embraces dualism for ease of discussion. It's the general position of psychology that without brains, there are no minds (and even with brains sometimes no minds). I think that position is a generally accepted metaphysical presupposition because of the failure of behaviorism which leans heavily on the primacy of material. Jaegwon Kim rejects downward causation...

Comment: @JD You can also be an external realist and agnostic with regards to the ontology of this external reality. If ontic realities are all we can know for certain, why go beyond science and phenomenology, which both are subject to historical and cultural hermeneutical settings and change?

Comment: And rightfully so in my NSHO. Remember, in analytic philosophy and naturalized epistemology, science is integrated into the movement, so the findings of cognitive science and psychology are admissible as philosophical statements.  Knowledge and knowledge systems are the result of physical systems. No medium, no message. No brain, no mind.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Ausgezeichnet, good sir. Not only agnosticism, but in my personal case, pluralism. Metaphysical presumption, as demonstrated by Euclid's geometry unfolding into a pluralism such as hyperbolic and spherical, to name two others, demonstrates the importance of seeing the adoption of a representation of external affairs as a pragmatic matter. Monisms, dualisms, or pluralisms are all subservient to the needs of the thinker. What other explanation explains the diversity and success of such a varied lot of ontologies, values, and epistemologies? I do have to ask...

Comment: Based on what do you make the claim that ontologies are more primary than metaphysical positions? Not that I disagree, but I'm curious by what road you reached that destination?

Comment: @JD To be precise, I wrote that I think epistemological and, closely linked, ontic categories are primary, since I do not see much of a difference between ontology and metaphysics. I, personally, got there through Dilthey and Plessner in the continental as well as Sellars and Putnam in the analytical tradition ( written about 60 years later respectively). That being said, this approach necessarily leads to a pluralism between historical and cultural settings or life-worlds. Adorno's final aphorism in *Minima Moralia* comes to mind

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I can't thank you enough for sharing your experience. Vielen dank!

Comment: Pain plays a key role in Cartesian as well as contemporary thinking about the problem of dualism. Theories of the psychological origins of pain symptoms persisted throughout the history of modern medicine and were not necessarily discouraged by Cartesian mental philosophy. Moreover, the recently developed biopsychosocial model of pain may have more in common with Cartesian dualism than it purports to have.https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12404076_Mind-Body_Dualism_and_the_Biopsychosocial_Model_of_Pain_What_Did_Descartes_Really_Say

Comment: Pain has always provided a test case for mind-body dualism. The issues of subjectivity and embodiment in relation to pain challenge modern understandings of mind and body.https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12404076_Mind-Body_Dualism_and_the_Biopsychosocial_Model_of_Pain_What_Did_Descartes_Really_Say

Comment: Continued....Pain serves as evidence for 
Descartes overall thesis of mind and body as conjoint, but different,substances.It certainly is a problematic thesis,and one which has attracted many counter-arguments.One of the subtleties of Cartesian dualism, however, is to maintain that soul and body are completely different kinds of substance, but that nonetheless they are “closely joined” and “intermingled.”Contemporary critics have often over-emphasized Descartes’ separation of the substances, and ignored his proposed union, even though his account of this union is fraught with problems.

Comment: In conclusion, Pain is the first Evil. So the concept of dualism of body-mind widely accepted since we have Problem of Evil. Also pain means resisting on the change, which change is the Universal reality. For example universe expanding , this means that it changing. So resisting on change bring pain, while change has no pain, (from eastern philosophy Buddha)

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this question, it is important to explain the purpose and reasoning behind it.
In the proposition below Spinoza announced, in his 'Ethics' Part 2- on the Origin and Nature of the Mind, his entirely revolutionary recognition of the presence and operating principles of the human mind and equally important of its union with and dependence on its body for knowledge concerning the sensible world. In other words, he resolved the mind/body problem.
Unfortunately, a series of events ensued which kept this discovery from reaching any audience which could appreciate its importance for science and epistemology in general. Spinoza's work was banned shortly after his death primarily because he wrote a book called, the 'Theological/Political Treatise' in which he pilloried established religion including all of christianity and islam as being riddled with superstitious cant, built-in to the scriptures so as to control the masses and to manipulate their lives.
It took over 150 years for the misunderstandings of Spinoza's system to come clear and it is only recently that the true merit of his scientific, ontological, epistemological and ethical contributions are slowly coming to light.
While Spinoza was outcast, the capability as scientist, mathematician and metaphysician of Descartes came to the fore and his system came to be regarded as the foremost and leading theories about human nature and humans place and connection with the external environment.

Once Descartes split the world from the human perspective into two spheres, essentially mind (soul or spirit) and extended substance (body) this cleared the way for an unbounded movement towards a mechanistic world view which has permeated philosophy and essentially continues to do so today. He viewed 'matter' as inert substance, which required an external force to account for any physical change and removed any dynamic or causal element to the sensible world. By making matter inert, he voided the possibility about and certain knowledge about the 'world. The 'idealists' came along and removed and possibility of a 'knower'. Taken together, materialism and idealism obliterate any possibility of garnering any verifiable knowledge about the world.
Today, philosophy appears to be attempting to work its way out of this corner which these two overriding systems painted it into.
This world view now permeates so much of philosophical theoretic frames that it is not clear that if anywhere, the mechanistic/duality is even considered to have any other alternative as a 'given' as a basis for scientific theory.

And so the purpose of this question and now this answer is to introduce the notion that Spinoza positing of a human mind united with its body and acting as a 'potent agency' in the accumulation of certain knowledge stands as a viable alternative to the contemporary philosophical systems currently on offer.

Spinoza's more detailed and easier to understand exposition of this can be found in his TIE (Tractatus Emendatione Intellectus)
Prop. XXI. "This idea of the mind is united to the mind in the same way as the mind is united to the body.
Proof.—That the mind is united to the body we have shown from the fact, that the body is the object of the mind; and so for the same reason the idea of the mind must be united with its object, that is, with the mind in the same manner as the mind is united to the body."

Statement from Antonio Damasio, author of 'Looking for Spinoza':
"According to Descartes' famous dualist theory, human beings were composed of physical bodies and immaterial minds. Spinoza disagreed. In "The Ethics," his masterwork, published after his death in 1677, he argued that body and mind are not two separate entities but one continuous substance."
"Science is proving Spinoza more current," Dr. Damasio said over tea at his hotel during a recent visit to New York. "He intuited the basic mechanism of the emotions."

Brief capsule of Descartian dualism:
..."when Descartes, in the first half of the seventeenth century, said that there are only two kinds of things or substances in nature, namely, extended substances and thinking substances, or bodies and spirits; that, in bodies, everything is reducible to extension with its modifications of form, divisibility, rest and motion, while in the soul everything is reducible to thinking with its various modes of pleasure, pain, affirmation, reasoning, will, etc...; when he in fact reduced all nature to a vast mechanism, outside of which there is nothing but the soul which manifests to itself its existence and its independence through the consciousness of its thinking, he brought about the most important revolution in modern philosophy.  To understand its significance however an account must be given of the philosophical standpoint of the time."

The point of view expressed here is not anti-anything, but rather pro-philosophy. It is not denigrating the scientific process, which results speak for themselves. It is not the work of science that is being called into question, it is what is theorized about the scientific platform or paradigm.
Thanks to everyone who took the time to comment. All the Best, CMS

Comment: This answer does still not justify the faulty assumptions of the question. Philosophy has moved beyond Spinoza for quite some time now, beginning in the ~1880s (Dilthey's historicised a priori) and broadly accepted since the ~1960s (pragmatist life-worlds and the hermeneutical circle as limits of expressivity through language) IMHO. This does not belittle the indeed remarkable work of Spinoza, who was way ahead of his time (Jacobi and Mendelssohn argued about this as early as the 1780s!), but the whole notion of certain, eternal knowledge is really getting nowhere these days.

Comment: Your view doesn't denigrate science. In fact, the rejection of Cartesian duality tends to be a popular view of materialists following [Ryle's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake).

Comment: @Philip Hocking- Why you would accept someone else's rejection of Spinoza is beyond me. Try a careful reading, without imposing presuppositions or contemporary defintions, of "On the Improvement of the Understanding" and then let me know your impressions. Meanwhile, to gain some insight into why Spinozan commentaries are misleading, please see my, 'Footnote Fixation', on my Academia.edu website. Cheers,

Comment: It's not like I hadn't been where you are. I've had this after extensive study of Kant. And late Husserl. And Wittgenstein. And Spinoza. And Sellars. And Putnam. The feeling that they, finally, gave me the profound truth I was searching for. But I went further, deeper, and realised that at the bottom of it, even the language allegedly denoting this truth is plastic, arbitrary, subject to change and that no single expression of any kind of truth is eternal. The later the authors, the more explicit this self-reflection. And then I read Plessner. And there, it is even part of the principles.

Comment: @Philip Hocking- and so, it took a sociologist to shake you from your philosophic slumbers, bully for you. And now, if I hurry, I can bask in the sunshine of your wisdom, mend the error of my ways and, dare I hope for it, become exactly like you. What a distinct honor awaits me. JUST JOKING! Cheers, Charles